# Parse.com date saving incorrectly

Tags: android, date, parse-platform

I'm using Parse as a data store for an app I'm building. I have a `Date` parameter within the class that stores the expiry date of a food that is saved to Parse. The date is inputted using a datepicker (code below)

The date picker is created as such:

```
 final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                                  int dayOfMonth) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                updateLabel();
            }

        };
        expiry_date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                new DatePickerDialog(AddItem.this, date, myCalendar
                        .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();

            }
        });
```

And the update label method converts it to a readable date and displayed in an EditText

```
 private void updateLabel() {

    String myFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"; //In which you need put here
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.UK);
    EditText update = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.expiry_date);
    update.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));

}
```

Then, when the date is saved, it converts in from a string to a date

```
   String dateString = expiry_date.getText().toString();
                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                Date convertedDate = new Date();

                try {
                    convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
                } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

This displays the correct date, as I'd expect. When saved however, the date is incorrect. For example, if I chose `28/08/2015`, it would be saved in the Parse core as `27/08/2015:2300`. It always saves as the day before with 11pm appended to it.

I wouldn't mind a time being appended to the date, but I'd prefer it to be 11:59pm on the day I picked, so I can compare dates later.

When the dates are displayed, they actually display the correct date (as in, the one picked from the date picker), rather than the saved date in Parse.

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String date = sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    Date datecomp = new Date();
    datecomp.getDate();

int check = object.getDate("expiry").compareTo(datecomp);
Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

I'm assuming this is something to do with the date conversion, but I can't figure out why it's doing this, and I've looked at a lot of different sources, but none seem to describe my problem. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Parse stores dates as GMT reference (not +3h or -2h GMT e.i someone from Turkey and someone from US have different time at the same moment.) So you should make localization on your application via keeping client timezone in parse db.

```
int  offsetInMs = 3600000;

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Date date = calendar.getTime();
TimeZone timeZone = calendar.getTimeZone();
TimeZone gmt0 = timeZone.getTimeZone("GMT0");
TimeZone gmtNewYork = timeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York");
TimeZone gmtLondon = timeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London");
TimeZone gmtIstanbul = timeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Istanbul");
TimeZone local = timeZone.getDefault();

System.out.println(gmt0.getID()+" -> "+gmt0.getOffset(date.getTime())/offsetInMs);
System.out.println(gmtNewYork.getID() + " -> " + gmtNewYork.getOffset(date.getTime())/offsetInMs);
System.out.println(gmtLondon.getID() + " -> " + gmtLondon.getOffset(date.getTime())/offsetInMs);
System.out.println(gmtIstanbul.getID() + " -> " + gmtIstanbul.getOffset(date.getTime())/offsetInMs);
System.out.println(local.getID()+ " -> " + local.getOffset(date.getTime())/offsetInMs);
```

i.e. Your local time zone is GMT+2 and local time is 15:00, 
Parse save it as 13:00(GMT). You shoud create a column named GMTOffset which keeps GMT+2.

Results: 
GMT0 -> 0, America/New_York -> -4, Europe/London -> 1, Asia/Istanbul -> 3, Asia/Istanbul -> 3

I think that Parse basetime is GMT0. Create a column named GMTOffset which keeps -4, 1, 3, 3 (user local offset).

Additionally, if you will use parse time in your application, Parse may localize time on the client side. Please check that also.
P.S. as my experience, client side time is not reliable, you should use your server(if exist) time.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I've removed the localisation format from my code, but it's still saving the same way at the backend

Comment: apologies, haven't had a change to look at this yet. Will accept answer once I've tried it out